# VPN Connection screen execution file

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

I would like to know what is the executable file name for the Windows VPN connection window and what folder it normally resides.

[image: VPN Connection window]

Comment: Have you checked any shortcut link?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have already store at least one VPN connection, then you can call it by giving the command

> rasphone

which will open your VPN address book where you can choose your connection.

Now you can call dialog window for a specific VPN Connection (let's say with the name `PEPVPN`) with

> rasdial "PEPVPN"

or you can push your credentials on the same command if you want to dial it directly

> rasdial "PEPVPN"  "jasons"  "yourPassword"

or disconnect

> rasdial "PEPVPN" /disconnect

Both executable files are in `c:\Windows\system32\`

Microsoft links with information about [rasdial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779544(v=ws.10)#using-rasdial-1) and [rasphone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/555935)